# Avro / Schema Registry - Make new field that is non-nullable / required

Tags: avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm starting to use Avro / Confluent's Schema Registry and .avsc files and want to add a new field that is required in the schema.

The old schema is like this for example:

```
{
  "name": ...
  "fields": [
    {"name": "one", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

I wanto to change it to:

```
{
  "one": string,
  "two": string,
}
```

How do I go about making the `two` field required / non-nullable **when trying to evolve a schema** ? Because I have to add a `default` value to it it will always be able to be one or the other.

**Edit**

It is worth pointing out that I'm using Confluent's Schema Registry and trying to Evolve a Schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just solved my own question. For future reference:

It is not possible to set an absolutely required field when using **Compatibility: BACKWARDS** obviously it would break the rest of the schema.

So the answer to this I guess would be setting it to **NONE** (in my case).

Any other answers with insights would be helpful, but I'm going with this solution by now!

Answer (score 0):

The default compatibility of the schema registry is `BACKWARDS`.  See https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#summary.

This means that any consumer updated to use the new schema will be able to read old messages produced with the previous schema.  This is useful when you can't synchronize the deployments of producers and consumers.  It can also be useful if messages are persisted and consumers may replay old messages, eg Kafka.

The strategy with backwards-compatible schemas is to upgrade the consumers first, guaranteeing they can still read messages from the existing producer, then later update the producers.

This shows a path to add the required field, albeit with multiple deployments.  Starting with schema fields like

```
[
  {"name": "one", "type": "string"}, 
]
```

add a new field with a default. Eg

```
[
  {"name": "one", "type": "string"}, 
  {"name": "two", "type": "string", "default": ""}
]
```

Any consumer using this updated schema can still handle messages without the `two` field by assuming the default.

Finally, once consumers and producers are updated and you are sure no messages of the original schema might be consumed, then you can remove the default and deploy consumers and producers again.

```
[
  {"name": "one", "type": "string"}, 
  {"name": "two", "type": "string"}
]
```

Consumers using this new schema without the default can still read messages with the previous schema with the default, although not the original without the field `two`.

This does assume that the empty string is a sane default for the new field `two`.  Depending on the application, it might need a different default.

It can be demonstrated that the compatibility checks are OK by running a local schema registry with default `BACKWARDS` compatibility.  For example, on my local machine running the schema registry on port 8081 and using `curl`:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"TestRecord\", \"fields\":[{\"name\": \"one\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}"}'
{"id":1}
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"TestRecord\", \"fields\":[{\"name\": \"one\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"two\", \"type\": \"string\", \"default\": \"\"}]}"}'
{"id":2}
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"TestRecord\", \"fields\":[{\"name\": \"one\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"two\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}"}'
{"id":3}
```